# How can i convert this statement to Jquery Completely

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
     if(document.getElementById('txt1') != null){
    $("#txt1").val(document.getElementById('txt1').value.toUpperCase());        
}
```

How can i convert this statement to Jquery Completely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a function with [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```
$("#txt1").val(function(i, val) { return val.toUpperCase(); });
```

...and it it doesn't find an `id="txt1"` element it just won't run on any, that's the way jQuery chains work, so your `if()` check is taken care of as well.

Comment: smart approach! didn't know `val` behaves like that.

Comment: @pex - yup, since 1.4 almost anything similar does, `.text()`, `.width()`, `.height()`, etc.

Comment: You are on fire today with passing functions to setters!

Answer (score 0):

or like this

```
var $txt = $("#txt");
if($txt.length){
  $txt.val($txt.val().toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the if statement

Comment: he said how to convert it completely. if he wants to see THAT if statement converted to jquery, THIS is how you would do it

Comment: jQuery does the `if(el)` part, so it's converted completely without the `if` anyway